# Build failed: directory does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio

Had a working project on a PC.

After transfering project on other PC (with installing Studio from scratch), unable to build the project now. Getting:

> Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:dataBindingExportBuildInfoDebug'.
>
>   > Directory 'Z:\path_to_proj\app\build\intermediates\data-binding-info\debug'
>   >     specified for property 'xmlOutFolder' does not exist.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1s

Any clues where to dig?

Comment: Suggest deleting the *.idea files and re-importing the project inside Android Studio instead of just trying to open it.

Comment: Good point. I didn't touch the *.idea files, but **importing** instead of opening did the trick. If you put your comment as an answer, I will approve it.